# BottomNavigationView with NavigationComponent does not work after navigating programmatically

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I created a minimal reproducible example from an ongoing Android project that I develop. It has 3 screens: *Home*, *dashboard* and *Notifications*, that are navigatable via a `BottomNavigationView`. The problem is when I try to navigate from the *Home* page to the *Dahsboard* page upon a button press, the icon of *Home* in the`BattomNavigationView` does not respond anymore.

Below is a gif that shows what I am trying to explain:
[image: Problem illustration gif]

[See the original video](https://youtube.com/shorts/o9YhuFzGk1E?si=T4bKIuiHQm2etJEX)

I expect it to navigate back to *Home* page when I clik it. But it does not navigate back. It only does when I click the back button of the Android's navigation bar. What am I missing here? Thank you.

I've created the example using Android Studio's *Bottom Navigation Views Activity*. Here is the code where I navigate programmatically:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    
    final Button button = binding.button;
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
        navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
    });
    return root;
}
```

Here is another way I tried with no avail and the same result:

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.navigation_dashboard));
```